# Ошибка при выполнении GetCurrentProcess

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Пытаюсь получить handle процесса, командой:

```
invoke GetCurrentProcess
```

В EAX получаю: FFFFFFFF
Что для этой команды еще нужно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Why does GetCurrentProcess return -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818173/why-does-getcurrentprocess-return-1)

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка: [согласно документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess) `GetCurrentProcess` возвращает псевдо-хэндл текущего процесса, который равен -1 (`0xFFFFFFFF`). В будущих версиях Windows это может измениться, но сейчас это -1.

Реальный хэндл текущего процесса можно получить с помощью функций `DuplicateHandle` или  `OpenProcess` (как указано по ссылке выше).